# What is faster for the method? Thread or "oneline method" - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I have a method which should run very fast. The speed of the program is not important, the only thing that is important is that the method, which is calling the following code, is fast. I have two options, first one is that I open a new Thread, second one is run the method directly.

Option one:

```
new Thread(() -> executeProgram(programs.get("progname"))).start();
```

Option two:

```
executeProgram(programs.get("progname.jar"));
```

The "executeProgram" method is this:

```
private void executeProgram(File program){
    try {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", program.getAbsolutePath()).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Benchmark both of them and you will see?!

Comment: premature optimisation is just about never a good thing. I've this nagging feeling you won't notice the difference on any modern hardware, and any ancient hardware won't have the JVMs to run either anyway.

Comment: definitely premature optimisation - the cost of starting that external process will be *far* greater than that of executing the function itself.

Comment: Here, First approach which is lamda approach is a non-blocking more like async, but the second approach is blocking. and on the modern machines you won't notice any big difference as @Alnitak and others are commented.

Comment: @Nityanarayan44 Java docs say: "There is no requirement that a process represented by a Process object execute asynchronously or concurrently with respect to the Java process that owns the Process object." - so even if you start the Process in a thread it _might_ block the entire JVM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a new thread<sup>1</sup> to perform a task is slower than just performing the task.

However, in general, performing a task on a separate thread is *qualitatively different*.  It allows the current thread to do something else rather than waiting for the task to complete.

However #2, the specific task you are performing here is:

```
  new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", program.getAbsolutePath()).start();
```

which launches an external process to run a program, *and does not wait for it to finish*.  This is unlikely to block for an appreciable time<sup>2</sup>, so there is little (if any) advantage in doing this in a separate thread.

---

<sup>1 - Using an existing thread (e.g. via a thread pool managed by an `ExecutorService` instance) will be faster.  But even so, it is not clear that it is worth the effort to do this.</sup>

<sup>2 - A commenter pointed out that a `Process` is not required to run asynchronously with the thread that launched it.  Indeed, it is possible that starting the process will block the thread or the entire JVM.  This is unlikely on a typical modern platform with multiple cores.  On a platform with a single core, starting a second thread may cause the first one to be suspended ... so you still may not get asynchronous execution.</sup>

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what i wanted to know. Thanks